# How can I implement cookieless flash messages on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, cookieless

I'm developing a facebook app so **I can't rely on cookies due to P3P** (Privacy Preferences Project) and yep, it's a damn pain (see [slides 18 and 19 on this slideshare about Rails and Facebook apps](http://www.slideshare.net/cmercier/things-i-learned-writing-a-facebook-canvas-app) for a picture of it)...

In a facebook app every cookie, from browsers perspective, is a **third-party cookie**. And many browsers block them by default.

So my question is: *How can I implement flash messages without rely on cookies?*

**UPDATE:**

I modified `session_store.rb` and the DB accordingly. Now the sessions are stored on DB but the flash messages are still relying on cookies... Any idea please?

**UPDATE#2:**

I finally found a workaround, see my answer below. Best thing to do would be to *ajax everything* (according to the above-linked slideshare) but as a quick fix my solution should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a **workaround** implementing my own (simple) flash messages and passing them through the params from one request to another.

First of all, I overwritten `default_url_options` in `application_controller.rb` to append to every request a :my_flash param:

```
def default_url_options 
  { :my_flash => @my_flash }
end
```

Then, always in `application_controller.rb`, I wrote a `my_flash_from_params` before_filter to set the `@my_flash` variable:

```
def my_flash_from_params
  @my_flash = params[:fb_flash]
end
```

Finally I rendered the following `_my_flash.html.erb` partial in `application.html.erb`

```
<div class="my_flash">
  <%= my_flash %>
</div>
```

Calling:

```
 <%= render :partial => "layouts/my_flash", :locals => {:my_flash => @my_flash} if @my_flash %>
```

If you want to try this solution see also [this answer about default_url_options rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473600/869616).

Answer (score 0):

Flash messages are built on top of the session. So you could still rely on the flash if you change the session store to use the database. This can be easily done by editing `config/initializers/session_store.rb` and following the instructions on that file.

Here's more information on the topic: [Action Controller Overview -> Session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)

Comment: I followed the instructions, and now the sessions are stored on the DB but the flash messages are still relying on cookies! Now that's weird... any idea?

Comment: You're right, according to the doc "All session stores use a cookie to store a unique ID for each session (you must use a cookie, Rails will not allow you to pass the session ID in the URL as this is less secure).". Sorry :(

Comment: Besides, handling the session in the DB doesn't work for a multi-dynos application... It's a real pain to handle sessions without cookies. Thank you anyway.