# How to bypass default_url_options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

In my last Rails project I had to overwrite `default_url_options` in `application_controller.rb` to always pass a param through every request, like this:

```
def default_url_options 
  { :my_default_param => my_param_value }
end
```

Now every url helper attaches a my_default_param at the end of every generated url.
For instance `user_url(@current_user)` generates a url like:

```
http://www.example.com/users/1?&my_default_param=my_param_value
```

**But sometimes I need to generate the url without my_default_param**. Is there some option I can pass to the url helper so that `user_url(@current_user, some_option: some_option_value`) will return only:

```
http://www.example.com/users/1?&my_default_param=my_param_value
```

?

PN: I already tried with `:overwrite_params=> { }` but it doesn't work, probably because it's evaluated before default_url_options.

**And if not, is there another way to obtain the @current_user url without the my_default_param attached?**

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to override `default_url_options` can't you just do the following: `user_url(id: @current_user, my_default_param: nil)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default_url_options` [has one param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/default_url_options) `options` which you could use as you wish:

```
def default_url_options( options = {} )

  use_defaults = options.delete( :use_defaults )

  if use_defaults
    { :my_default_param => 'my_param_value' }
  else
    {}
  end

end
```

Or you could reverse the logic:

```
def default_url_options( options = {} )

  ignore_defaults = options.delete( :ignore_defaults )

  if ignore_defaults
    {}
  else
    { :my_default_param => 'my_param_value' }
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't get it to work, how am I supposed to call `user_url(@current_user)` to ignore defaults? (I prefer the reversed logic)

Comment: I tried with `user_url(@current_user, ignore_defaults: true)` but it doesn't work. Any idea please?

Comment: It ironically generates a url with `?my_default_param=my_param_value&ignore_defaults=true`...what am I missing?

Comment: Well, seems like it was long time ago. If you still need an answer - I've provided above monkey patching for rails method which you should add to your initializers. In general, you should override `default_url_options` for `ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Base`.